# How can I plot a legend with multiple rows and columns?

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I'm working on a bar-plot like this:

[image]

I want to move the legend to the upper-left corner and upon the top spine. But it is too high and will covered some bars. So I want to change it as 2 rows and 4 columns. How should I do? I've searched about 1 hour and have no result,  maybe I got wrong keywords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [fine docs](https://matplotlib.org//api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html)

> ncol : integer
>         The number of columns that the legend has. Default is 1.